# How to bulk update Jenkins jobs config xml files?

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, xml-parsing

I'm a newbie in Jenkins and Groovy. I need to bulk update Jenkins jobs config files. For example, changing the Git URL for a large number of jobs or adding a timeout behaviour. To do that I'm generating a list of Jenkins job names using this piece of Groovy code:

```
import com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.*
void processFolder(Item folder) {
    folder.getItems().each {
        if(it instanceof Folder) {
            processFolder(it)
        } else {
            processJob(it)
        }
    }
}

void processJob(Item job) {
    println job.fullName
}

Jenkins.instance.getItems().each {
    if(it instanceof Folder) {
        processFolder(it)
    } else {
        processJob(it)
    }
}
```

Inside processJob() method, I'm planning to fetch the job's config file using job name

```
void processJob(Item job) {
    AbstractItem item = (AbstractItem)Jenkins.getInstance().getItem(job.name);
    XmlFile configXml = item.getConfigFile();
    File xmlfile = configXml.getFile();
    def xml = new XmlParser().parse(xmlfile)
}
```

Sample config file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@3.4.1">
    <configVersion>2</configVersion>
    <userRemoteConfigs>
      <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        <url>https://github.com/gitboy/Backup.git</url>
      </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
    </userRemoteConfigs>
    <branches>
      <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
        <name>*/master</name>
      </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    </branches>
</project>
```

Here I need to add a new element TIMEOUT after the URL tag.

But the XmlParser gives an output that looks something like this:

```
project[attributes={}; value=[actions[attributes={}; value=[]], 
description[attributes={}; value=[]], keepDependencies[attributes={}; value=
[false]], properties[attributes={}; value=[]], scm[attributes=
{class=hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM, plugin=git@3.4.1}; value=
[configVersion[attributes={}; value=[2]], userRemoteConfigs[attributes={}; 
value=[hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig[attributes={}; value=
[url[attributes={}; value=
[https://github.com/gitboy/Backup.git]]]]]], 
branches[attributes={}; value=[hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec[attributes={}; 
value=[name[attributes={}; value=[*/master]]]]]]]
```

I couldn't find any examples on how to add a new child element using XmlParser/XmlSlurper.

Is it the right approach to bulk update Jenkins jobs configuration? Appreciate any help/suggestion.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `add` method in `NodeList`

```
    NodeList config = node.userRemoteConfigs."hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig"
    config.add(0, new Node(config[0], "TIMEOUT", "theValue"))
```